# Windows-7 Username has changed

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I've been using Virtual PC XP on windows-7 and it keeps losing the password.

But even worse I now have a windows-7 user called "le" when before I always log on as "Developer" ! I assume it is the same account because the password works.

I've been using the new Virtual PC integration.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The display name of your user account may have changed. You can verify this in Control Panel → User Accounts → "Change your account name".  This will change the "Full Name" property of your account, which is what is displayed on the Welcome screen.